# UIWebView content how to resize/scale it?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I came to a point where I was able to lock the horizontal scroll as I wanted however when I rotate from landscape to portrait the content is still to large. I need to resize/scale it down myself but I don't know how to so far I use this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://igo.nl";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webView loadRequest:requestObj];
    _webView.scrollView.bounces = false;
    _webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    _webView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
}


    - (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
    {

        if(fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        {
            //_webView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, _webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);
        }
        else
        {
            //[_webView reload];
            _webView.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320,_webView.bounds.size.height);
            _webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, _webView.frame.size.height);
            _webView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, _webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);

        }
    }
```

EDIT:
What I seem to need is that the content is zoomed out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the delegate methods of `UIWebViewDelegate`

```
@interface YOUR_CLASS : PARENT_CLASS <UIWebViewDelegate>
```

In `viewDidLoad`

```
...
[_webView setDelegate:self];
...
```

Call the delegate method

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {

    [webView.scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake(webView.frame.size.width, webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)];

}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    [_webView reload];    //Or use meta tag

    [_webView.scrollView setContentSize: CGSizeMake([_webView.scrollView.contentSize.width, _webView.scrollView.contentSize.height)];
}
```

You have to add `meta` tag to your `HTML` file

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

or simply reload the webView

```
[_webView reload];
```

Comment: thanks for the setContentSize trick ! your code was not enough for me because I'm switching from a webview content that I can scroll and zoom to a fixed-width and no-scroll content. Calling this code exactly when changing viewport meta tag was not enough, it seems that I have to wait until the page is loaded for this to work (but i'm in a single-page app that's why the webViewDidFinishLoad was not enough).

Answer (score 0):

try in

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
------
}
```

calculate using

```
self.view.bounds.size.width,
self.view.bounds.size.height
```

Comment: Didn't work I am calculating in the `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation`method

Comment: _webView.bounds.size.height it previous frame  set so better use 200 like that

    _webView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200);

Comment: The problem is not with the height I the content width is too big for the frame and I don't want to use horizontal scrolling

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{

if(toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait && toInterfaceOrientation!=UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown )
   {


   }
 else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation ==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
   {

   }
}
```